# redirect from Control Panel (top right link) not working

Tags: url, rewrite

There is a similar issue mentioned here, but the answer doesn't work for me...

If I click on the site link it'll forward as follows:

```
http://example.nl/?URL=http://example.nl/
```

This works for all my EE sites, except one. This shows a blank page. I have completely removed the .htaccess file to test if that was the cause, but no change. Since this normally presents a EE page like this:

```
To proceed to the URL you have requested, click the link below:

http://example.nl/
```

I assume the issue is EE related? Or is it server related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared I hadn't updated the index.php file in the root of the site, which handles the redirect. Not something I do with every upgrade, but can apparently mess things up if you don't.